# Are there any non-binary pronouns or neopronouns in Spanish?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, pronombres, neologismos, neutralidad-de-género

Is there any existing or proposed third-person singular pronoun that, unlike "él" or "ella", does not necessarily specify the sex of the person referred to? (I understand that nobody wants to be called "ello".)

---

¿Existe o hay propuesto algún pronombre de tercera persona en singular que, al contrario que "él" o "ella", no especifique necesariamente el sexo de la persona referida? (Entiendo que nadie quiere que se le llame "ello".)

Comment: Lo primero que se me ocurre si bien no es un pronombre en tercera persona, sería el trato de usted. Aunque sigue existiendo la dificultad para España.

Comment: El Código de conducta solo dice esto "Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.".  Pues simplemente reemplazar "el o ella" por el nombre de usuario (@user) y lista la incertidumbre. De resto siempre se debe usar los pronombres y artículos normales.

Comment: this is a very polemic subject right now, and is being discussed by large and small organizations about the "gender neutrality and the right for the women to be mentioned" (which is actually a contradiction) but in regards of conduct code of what is considered right and what not... and not use of the language i think this question is offtopic... or may be even belong to the Meta

Comment: Aunque el origen de la pregunta sea un tema de Meta, la pregunta vale por sí misma: el tema del llamado "lenguaje inclusivo" está presente en muchos debates en la "vida real" fuera de SE. Yo no cerraría esta pregunta, a menos que empiece a atraer respuestas que no sean más que opiniones (o panfletos).

Comment: I think we should have two questions: the first on this issue related to Spanish language (i.e. this one) and the second in meta about an adaptation of the Code of Conduct to SSE. I'm not sure about SO in Spanish: they have their own meta but I think that, since they also use Spanish, we should use the same rules, shouldn't we?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv - I personally don't know that site at all.  I'd say, let's forge ahead and *señalar la pauta* here, and if they want to follow our lead, great; if they come up with some modifications that we like, we can certainly take them on board.  But we already have so many constraints on the system that I would not like to add a "our two sites have to match and be perfectly consistent" constraint on top of the others. // I like your idea of posting a question on our Meta.

Comment: @walen I didn't mean we were under any obligation but it was our duty. E.g., aparente001 is trying to express things that actually belong to the meta question in their answer below.

Comment: I was going to comment with the Élle already linked by ukemi, and ask for clarification. "El pronombre _elle_ es una propuesta de pronombre neutro que no existe en el idioma español." At the same time, the new FAQ states neopronouns like xe, zir, ne... as valid (actually, **mandatory** if a user requests to be addressed by those, according to Q11: "If they are the pronouns stated by the individual, you must respect that and use them. **Grammar concerns do not override a person’s right to self identify.**" ) Are we looking for grammatically correct pronouns? because I assume neopronuns won't be

Comment: @Diego - Lo que creo (y esto es solamente mi opinión personal) es que si alguien viene a este sitio y *pide* que los usuarios utilicen un pronombre no estandar, inclusive uno de aquellos que provienen de otros idiomas como el inglés, deben usarlo. No dificultará la comprensión si se incluye una nota que explique el significado. Como analogía, si alguien prefiera un nombre (o un nombre de usuario) que no fuera del español,  lo usaríamos. Hasta si quisiera utilizar un título extranjero, lo usaríamos (p. ej. *san* o *sri*).

Comment: IMHO, comment above should be in the (ATOW nonexistent) meta question. We're mixing things up.

Answer (score 6):

Just for reference, there exists a "brief" guide about this topic in Fundéu:

[Lenguaje inclusivo: una breve guía sobre todo lo que está pasando](https://www.fundeu.es/lenguaje-inclusivo/)

It consists of 9 articles, but I think only three apply to this question:

1. [La x, la @, la -e](https://www.fundeu.es/lenguaje-inclusivo/la-x-la-@-la-e.html)
   Though expressive **graphic** resources, they are discouraged due to the impossible pronunciation. (Additionally, IMO, [Charlie made a good point about reading software used by blind people](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31712/are-there-any-non-binary-pronouns-or-neopronouns-in-spanish/31725#comment56660_31720).)
2. [El masculino genérico](https://www.fundeu.es/lenguaje-inclusivo/masculinogenerico.html)

   > **La postura académica es clara** a este respecto: en español el
   >   masculino es el género no marcado.   En gramática un elemento no
   >   marcado  es:
   >
   > - el de sentido más general;
   > - el de distribución más amplia;
   > - el que se recupera por defecto cuando no hay morfemas específicos.
   >
   > (...)
   >   La última Gramática académica ofrece principalmente **dos motivos** en defensa de este masculino genérico:
   >
   > - La **economía lingüística**: se considera que las alternativas, como desdoblar cada apelación en dos géneros, son un circunloquio
   >     innecesario la mayor parte de las veces.
   > - La **concordancia gramatical**: ante soluciones como el desdoblamiento sistemático, pasaría a ser mucho más complicada.

   But, from Fundéu, they think otherwise:

   > **En la Fundéu creemos** que esos son los detonantes que empiezan a impulsar un cambio gramatical en una lengua (más lentos, más
   >   complicados de alcanzar que cualquier cambio ortográfico o léxico).
   >   Cuando estos usos se generalicen, cuando la mayoría de los hablantes
   >   en su día a día, con naturalidad, entiendan que el femenino es más
   >   adecuado que el masculino en algunas situaciones y lo empleen así,
   >   estaremos ante un fenómeno mayoritario; este uso del femenino será un
   >   consenso tácito en la mente de los hablantes. Y entonces la Gramática
   >   académica, notaria de la lengua, previsiblemente registrará que el
   >   masculino ya no es la única forma correcta de referirse a un grupo
   >   mixto.
3. [Nombres de colectivos y otros recursos](https://www.fundeu.es/lenguaje-inclusivo/nombres-colectivos-y-otros-recursos.html)

   Sustantivos colectivos (*persona interesada*, *ciudadanía*), epicenos (*cónyuge*, *clientela*), abstractos (*dirección*, *presidencia*), paráfrasis (*el ser humano*, *la clase trabajadora*), omisión del sujeto (*pueden enviar*, *se podrá reclamar*), empleo de relativos (*quien solicite*), reformulaciones (*tienen mucho interés*), aposiciones explicativas (*tanto hombres como mujeres*), omisión del sustantivo (*menores de 12 años*), determinantes y pronombres sin marca de género (*cada participante*).

And, obliquely:

1. [El desdoblamiento](https://www.fundeu.es/lenguaje-inclusivo/desdoblamiento.html)

   Excluding specific cases:

   > **La doble mención**, al masculino y al femenino, **es general en los vocativos** (fórmulas fijas como *señores y señoras* `(sic)`, *damas y
   >   caballeros*), en los que se interpreta como una marca de cortesía;
   >   **pero, salvo esos usos**, la Academia indica que **resulta artificioso** `(sic)` y que se trata de un «circunloquio innecesario
   >   cuando el empleo del género no marcado es suficientemente explícito
   >   para abarcar a los individuos de uno y otro sexo».

   But inclusive language guides usually offer this splitting as an option. Nevertheless...

   > ... **estos manuales no proponen que se desdoblen sistemáticamente todos**
   >   **los** determinantes, nombres, adjetivos, etc., **que tienen flexión**, sino
   >   que el desdoblamiento es una opción, entre muchas otras, a la que se
   >   puede acudir en ocasiones, siempre teniendo en cuenta que su empleo
   >   recurrente en textos redactados genera confusión y hastío en el
   >   lector.

The rest I think are more related to the use of expressions.

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning behind answering in english but quoting spanish texts without translation, wouldn't it make more sense to have either the full answer in spanish or to translate the quotes?

Comment: @BrianH. Anyway, once edited the question, my answer seems kinda out of place. It should be migrated to the equivalent in meta when available. When it's there, I'll translate it.

Comment: La postura académica está lejos de ser clara. En muchas facultades ya se permite el uso del lenguaje inclusivo. Además, ese supuesto ‘desdoblamiento’ ya está cayendo en desuso por ser redundante y porque da la sensación de que falta nombrar gente. Pero lo que queremos es *quitar* determinaciones, no agregarlas incesantemente

Answer (score 6):

Hay [*elle/élle*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89lle). No parece tan popular en el lenguaje inclusivo (escrito) como los alternativos *ell@, ellx* etc, pero tiene la ventaja de tener una pronunciación no ambiguo.

Comment: Esto lo prefería. Hay una posibilidad de confusión entre este pronombre y el pronombre femenino de la tercera persona en francés, pero obviamente hay palabras en uso general que tienen la misma desventaja, tal como con (que quiere decir idiota en francés). Utilizo la arroba, aunque no consistentemente, pero esto me parece mejor.

Comment: ¿Cómo se pronuncia?  ¿Como *eye*?

Comment: El nuevo [observatorio de palabras](https://www.rae.es/portal-linguistico/observatorio-de-palabras) de la RAE, que tiene como objetivo ofrecer información provisional sobre palabras y expresiones que aún no están en el diccionario pero que han generado dudas (neologismos, extranjerismos, tecnicismos, etc.) incluye el [pronombre _elle_](https://www.rae.es/observatorio-de-palabras/elle) en su lista de palabras observadas.

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience <strike>wrestling</strike> working with Spanish so as to implement gender ambiguity online, for myself, and for people whose gender is unknown to me.  I do this in English with *they, them, their, themselves*.  In Spanish it's not so easy.

I haven't found pronouns to be the major challenge, because our language's ability to omit the subject pronoun in most sentences has the side benefit of leaving the subject's gender ambiguous.

Also, the general "one" (*uno*) and the general "all" (*todos*) leave gender ambiguous.

The big challenge, in my experience, comes up as soon as I try to use an adjective to describe myself or some other person whose gender is unknown.  Most adjectives end in *-o*, and due to the gender agreement requirement of adjectives, we're normally forced to choose between *-o* and *-a*. Examples:

- I'm confused.  *Estoy confundido* or *Estoy confundida*, *No estoy seguro* / *No estoy segura* -- these immediately reveal a gender assumption.

I know of three workarounds:

1. Recast/rewrite:

- *Siento cierta incertidumbre sobre esto.*
- *Tengo algo de confusión al respecto.*

  - For "I am ready" (*Estoy listo / Estoy lista*): *Todo está listo.*
  - For "S/he's ready to sign the contract today": *¿Está de acuerdo con firmar el contrato hoy.*

2. Find an alternative adjective which doesn't end in a vowel, for example:

- For "Es listo/lista": *Es inteligente*.
- For "Está contento/contenta": *Es feliz*

Note, in my experience, this workaround is not available in most cases, and it can change the desired meaning.

3. Use **@**.

Examples:

- *Estoy confundid@.*
- *OP dijo que ya está list@ a considerar otras opciones.*

**I think the use of *@* in situations where the gender is unknown or ambiguous would get us to 95% compliance with the new Code of Conduct.**

---

Some challenges do remain.  For example, "parent" can be tricky.  I've often been able to solve it like this: *mamá o papá*, *mamás y papás*, and sometimes *padres de familia*.

- Is **a parent** going to be home?

> *Tú querías visitar a Tom hoy ¿no?  ¿Chequeaste si va a estar su mamá o papá en casa? Ya sabes, esa es la regla, no visitas si no está un adulto en casa.*

Here's a similar problem and the solution I've been using:

- Are you going to the movies with a friend? (Here, I want to leave the gender ambiguous when talking with my teenager.)

> *¿Vas al cine con algún amigo o amiga?*

Or, if I've gotten the impression there may be a *group* of friends involved, then:

> *¿Vas al cine con amigos?*

(It's often possible to use Option 2 here as well: *¿Vas al cine con un cuate?* or in some situations, one can ask, *¿Vas al cine con pareja?* -- This can function rather like the English "plus one.")

Up until now, the idea of using *@* hasn't met with general acceptance here at Spanish.SE. My hope is that it will be given serious consideration now.

Important note: if your pronoun is gendered, you'd still be able to talk about yourself with gendered adjectives, and others would still be able to talk about you with gendered adjectives.  I'm not suggesting a wholesale substitution of *@* in place of the final *-a* or *-o* in all adjectives describing people.

Comment: +1 for the exposition (in both meanings of that word), yet I have to say this sidesteps the letter, if not the spirit, of the question: what do we do with our (standard, gendered) singular 3rd person pronouns?

Comment: @pablodf76 - Or maybe I expanded the question. If you want me to shift my answer to a new question, I will.  Maybe "How shall we approach neutral gender communication here at Spanish.SE?", or -- I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What is the TL;DR? Are there any  non-binary or neopronouns we can use in Spanish?

Comment: I don't think a new question is necessary. I would rather wait for what @Charlie has to say.

Comment: @Diego - I don't know if there are any new inventions other than the @ trick, but for me the take-home message is *don't skip -- read the whole thing, which is not terribly long anyway; in Spanish we generally don't have to use a subject pronoun; for emphasis or other pronoun needs, be creative and don't be afraid to try things like "para él/ella," "por sí mism@."*

Comment: @walen - Sorry, I forgot to give you credit -- you also assisted behind the scenes, and thanks again.

Comment: I really like your exposition, but I feel this should be a very good answer for the Meta question "how do we adapt the CoC to Spanish". My question was really about pronouns or neopronouns in Spanish, such as the _élle_ ukemi found. I don't mind if the pronouns do not currently exist in Spanish, I was just curious about the existence of such pronouns as they exist in English. Of course, apart from the neopronouns the Spanish language has other challenges you have wonderfully exposed, but those were not really the aim of this question.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot, the problem with the use of the @ to express gender-neutrality is the reading software for blind people. Imagine the software reading aloud "estoy confundid arroba", and we are talking about inclusion here, so we must not make life more difficult for blind people, hence I discourage the use of the @ symbol in favor of other constructions. I'd better use "estoy confundide" for that purpose.

Comment: @Charlie - Would you do the honors and pose the Meta question?  Then I'll transfer my answer.

Comment: Una cosa que yo no he entendido (quizás porque soy un angloparlante nativo y a pesar de lo que algunas personas están argumentando creo que es significativamente más facil emplear lenguaje de genéro neutro en inglès) es ¿por qué formas tales como "todes" no son más populares? He visto el uso de la arroba y la x, pero aunque estas son adecuados al idiom escrito son dificiles de pronunciar. Una palabra como latinx se puede decir utilizando la pronunciaciòn, pero no puedo imaginar una forma comprensible de pronunciar "tod@s".

Comment: Habría pensado que algo como "todes" o "eses" sería lo más popular, porque es corto, se reconoce como español (foneticamente) y cumple con la pauta más comun de palabras neutras en español, pero parece que la x y la @ son más populares. Pues utilizo la segunda, pero si pensara que la gente la entendiera definitivamente prefería formas con "e" (o "u" o "i" u otra vocal).

Comment: Pues quería decir "adecuadas al idioma escrito" sin embargo ya es demasiado tarde, pero me entiendes.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Tip: when I have mistakes in my comment, I can edit it.  If I miss the five-minute window, I copy the existing comment, delete the original, and repost the comment, with the desired edits.  If I have a series of comments -- well, that is one of the reasons I love using a clipboard editor.  Tip #2: Complex ideas are easier for people to understand when I avoid long parenthetical phrases. // I hope you will contribute an answer!

Comment: @aparente001 - Creo que constituyó más bien una pregunta. Puesto que en inglés la forma más común por mucho es "they", que conforma muy bien a la estructura del idioma y es facil de utilizar, ¿por qué las formas mas comunes en español son distintas en esos aspectos? No lo sé, quizás sea que el lenguaje neutro es más corriente en inglés, mientras que en español mucha gente ya utiliza el masculino supuestamente generico. (Y ¿has tenido la oportunidad de echar un vistazo a mi pregunta sobre el autolike, la que cerraste por la falta de una imagen, que ahora hay?

Comment: Para ser claros, yo puse un voto entre cinco....  ¿Usaste un método creador de poner la imagen?  Salió muy borrosa.  Sin embargo, pude ampliarla lo suficiente para distinguir la frase.

Comment: La pregunta en Meta al respecto: [_How should we address people in Spanish in a gender-neutral way on our site?_](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3231/12637)

Comment: I suggest to remove all references to the "Code of Conduct" and to the moderation/administration of Stack Exchange from this answer, as those are meta topics that do not belong on the main site and do not answer the question.

Comment: Good one, @wimi, I suggest you doing so (everyone can edit and suggest edits, the status of the posts comes from the efforts of us all)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I know that, but as those are somewhat major edits, I did not want to do it without the agreement of the author. The author seems to have been inactive for a long time though...

Comment: @wimi oh, I see. In any case, I think [your edit](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/31720/revisions) has been very good and accomplishes this goal. Hopefully aparente will return some day and confirm they are ok with the changes. Thanks!